# Running background task for websockets in Python

Tags: python, websocket

I've started a project that requires and uses websockets to send information from server X to client Y, as intended.

However, I kept running into the issue where every 20 or so seconds the connection would be dropped since that's how TCP/IP is meant to be, so I need to send *heartbeats* per se.

Before I go on, if there's some other way of doing this (apart from sending a heartbeat) please let me know.

---

So the methodology I was going about to make the websocket before sending heartbeats was as such:

```py
async def listener(websocket, path, service):
  command = service['log_command']
  p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True)
  prev_sd = "-1"
  await heartbeat_manager(websocket)
  asyncio.sleep(5)
  while True:
    await websocket.send(p.stdout.readline())
```

The `while True` and after is all that we care about, my intention is to have the websocket send a heartbeat of some text every 5 seconds but don't know where at all to get started.

Sidenote: There's another function that I call that actually runs this websocket, but it's irrelevant to the question so I did not include it, but rest assured; it does exist (and all of this code is functional, but only for 20ish seconds before dying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Python's async/await mechanism, perhaps you could try using [asyncio subprocesses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) to let you await a subprocess's output streams. The following example code spawns the subprocess and checks for new lines available on standard output with a 5 second timeout, using [`asyncio.wait_for()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for); if no data is available to send, we deliver a heartbeat instead.

```py
import asyncio

async def listener(websocket, path, service):
    command = service['log_command']
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    ...
    while True:
        try:
            data = await asyncio.wait_for(p.stdout.readline(), timeout=5)
            websocket.send(data)
        except asyncio.TimeOutError:
            await websocket.send("heartbeat")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this results in ``RuntimeError: Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached``

Comment: If you're not running this from the main thread, there are [limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-and-threads). Otherwise, you could try adding a watcher to your loop [manually](http://www.decodednode.com/2018/11/asyncio-neweventloop-and-child-watchers.html)

Comment: That would be the reason, I'm running this subprocess inside a thread; although the link to attach the child watcher didn't exactly click for me mentally, mind explaining? Thanks!